# Catch a ControllerNotFoundException in CastleProject Monorail

Tags: controller, castle-windsor, configuration-files, castle, castle-monorail

I am using a standard Monorail/Windsor/ActiveRecord stack to build a web application. In the web application the controllers are registered (for Windsor) using a xml config file.

A ControllerNotFoundException will be (obviously) thrown by the MonoRailHttpHandlerFactory when a controller has not been defined in the config file.

Is there a way to catch this exception and to show a custom message to the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always find out what the error is in the Application_OnError() event handler in your GLobalApplication. We do something like this:

```
public virtual void Application_OnError()
    {
        var error = Server.GetLastError();

        if ( error.GetType() != typeof( ControllerNotFoundException ) )
            return;

        // We don't want these errors in the event log
        Server.ClearError();

        //Handle page not found

        Server.TransferRequest( "/rescue/pagenotfound" );
    }
```